# Squid Proxy - Hide Signs of Proxy Being Used

Tags: proxy, vps, squid

I've installed a Squid Proxy Server in a Windows VPS.
I will route browser and some other programs in my PC through that proxy, and I would like that all requests are sent to the websites just as if I was normally using those browsers/programs in the VPS.
Meaning, I would want that Squid does not add or remove any information, so that the information passed is exactly the same as if I was using those programs on the VPS itself.

I'm very very new to all of this, and I've been searching for answers, but many answers are very old and refer to previous versions of Squid, and also sometimes it is not clear the use case is the same as mine.

- The one setting that I have already added to the config file is "*via off*", which deletes the info about squid being used.
- I also see many mentions of adding "*forwarded_for delete*" or "*forwarded_for off*", but I'm not sure which is the best for my case, as I'm not sure if this header is passed at all in a normal connection.
- Finally, I see many reccommendations regarding [request_header_access](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/request_header_access/) and [reply_header_access](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/reply_header_access/), but honestly I could't really understand what they are for and if they are useful for my case, since they mention *anonymization*, and I'm not sure that means removing information (related with the VPS) that would be sent in a normal request.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Compare headers with and without proxy, and figure out how to disable unwanted headers? It is however off topic here imho.